# Ordering by child value CakePHP containable

Tags: php, cakephp, web-applications

Lecturers teach modules and some are module organisers. Here I am fetching the modules a Lecturer teaches:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'organiser' => '1',
        'module_id' => '2',
        'lecturer_id' => '1',
        'Module' => array(
            'code' => 'MOD2',
            'name' => 'Z Name'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'organiser' => '1',
        'module_id' => '1',
        'lecturer_id' => '1',
        'Module' => array(
            'code' => 'MOD1',
            'name' => 'Module Name'
        )
    )
)
```

How do I sort it by the module name? I have used a hasMany through relationship as additional data is needed in the join table (such as organiser). Here is the method I use to contain a Lecturer's data on their profile. The commented out line does not work.

```
public function get($id = null) {
    $this->contain(
        array(
            'User',
            'County.name',
            'School' => array(
                'fields' => array('code', 'name')
            ),
            'ModuleStaff' => array(
                'fields' => array('organiser'),
                'Module' => array(
                    'fields' => array('code', 'name'),
                ),
                // 'order' => 'Module.name',
            )
        )
    );
    return $this->findByUserId($id);
}
```

Here are my relationships for the ModuleStaff join class

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Lecturer' => array(
        'className' => 'Lecturer',
        'foreignKey' => 'lecturer_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Module' => array(
        'className' => 'Module',
        'foreignKey' => 'module_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

Adding name to the order value for Module does not work either as each ModuleStaff only links to one Module, I need to sort the actuall ModuleStaff objects by a value inside their child class.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put `'order' => 'Module.name'` element into `Module` array? Like this:

```
'ModuleStaff' => array(
    'fields' => array('organiser'),
    'Module' => array(
        'fields' => array('code', 'name'),
        'order'  => array('Module.name')
    )
)
```

Comment: Tried that and it didn't work, that would only work if each ModuleStaff contained multiple Modules